# timed click on a web form

Tags: web-applications, javascript

I'd like to automate the clicking of a web-form button, in order that the web form "submit" button be pressed at a certain time.   If possible, I'd like to do this on Firefox on a Mac, but I'm open to alternatives.

It's not obvious how to do this with Applescript or Mac's Automator.  I have some experience with VUgen from Mercury Interactive / HP, but AFAIrecall that's a paid-for tool, supporting IE on Windows.  I have an idea that it might be possible using Javascript, but I'm uncertain where I'd instantiate the Javascript, in order to click the button.

Comment: Are you talking as end user or as a developer?

Comment: End-user -- the webform is published by a 3rd party, and I'm hoping I can get the computer to click the "Next" at a pre-determined time.

Comment: In order to do this via javascript you'd need to save the script as a bookmark and click it once on the page (bookmark would need to start javascript: some javascript) not sure if this would be a useful solution to you or not

Comment: @Matt - embedding javascript in a bookmark sounds like it's the right scale for my need here.  I'll check into this more.

Comment: As this question is getting in to the realms of writing your own JavaScript I am migrating it to Stack Overflow as it is now off-topic for WebApps.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked a little bit at the bookmarklet idea I gave you and here is a jsfiddle with at the very least some starting code

http://jsfiddle.net/FGM9j/2/

```
<input type="submit" id="test" onclick="alert('worked')"></input>
function timerPassed()
{
    alert('timer'); //to show timer works
    document.getElementById('test').click();

}
window.setTimeout(timerPassed,3000);//function you want to call , time in milliseconds
```

Also certain input types cannot be run via javascript just as file.
The resulting bookmark would look something like:

```
  javascript:function timerPassed(){document.getElementById('test').click();}window.setTimeout(timerPassed,3000);
```

`setInterval` in place of `setTimeout` could be used instead if you wanted it to repeat the process, for example if things needed to meet a certain specification before the button was to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two existing framework which can make automate test web, web form is one of many things them can do, try to look:

- http://seleniumhq.org/
- http://www.iopus.com/imacros/

You can use it as web browser extension/addons or standalone framework with support programmable scripting.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @uoc-nguyen - I've tried Selenium IDE, and I'm now looking into flow control with goto_sel_ide.js. It appears I'll have to use a embed some javascript to compare the system time to a fixed value. Your suggestion of `iopus iMacros` looks like it might work. At first blush, it seems expensive.

Comment: It's easy way to test web, if you are looking for UI/Graphic testing, eg: click on javascript button, image... then I suggest you should have a look for Sikuli (http://sikuli.org/) it is image based action programming.

Comment: Alternatively if you want headless test (automate action on web page without open graphically window) then PhantomJS is a good way to go: http://www.phantomjs.org/

Comment: Thanks for the additional pointers - I wasn't aware of either tools. Sikuli in particular may work.  I'm also looking into Matt's "bookmarklet" suggestion (above).